# JNA passing Reference to Byte Array does not work correctly

Tags: java, memory-management, jna

my native code is:

```
int xlSetApplConfig(
char *appName,
unsigned int appChannel,
unsigned int hwType,
unsigned int hwIndex,
unsigned int hwChannel,
unsigned int busType)
```

I tried to express `appName` with a Pointer in Java like this:

```
    //integers..
    byte[] appnamebyte = new String("JEdit").getBytes();
    Pointer appname = new Memory(appnamebyte.length);
    appname.write(0, appnamebyte, 0, appnamebyte.length);
    int status = dll.INSTANCE.xlOpenPort(portHandle, appname, channelMask, permissionMask, 
    rxQueueSize,
    xlInterfaceVersion, busType);
```

the function is writing the byte array to the registry or somewhere and with a other Tool(given one) I can read the value.
If I start my code there is no error but the `appname` is not allways correct. Sometimes there are more charcacters than i want("JEdit  ?78ê").
Maybe somehow more memory than I want is allocated.
I also tried to pass an normal byte[] but with the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is that C strings must be null terminated.  Simply grabbing the bytes from the `String` only gives you the characters J, E, d, i, and t.  Your array needs to have a sixth byte with a value of 0 to work properly.

One way to do this is to keep the `Pointer` mapping you have and allocate the extra byte yourself and then write the bytes to that native memory using [`Pointer.setString()`](https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#setString-long-java.lang.String-):

```java
Memory buffer = new Memory(6);
// make sure the last byte is 0
memory.clear(); // could also just set the last byte
buffer.setString(0, "JEdit");
```

(Note that this relies on the default platform encoding, which is generally a bad idea.  You should specify the encoding; in this case `US-ASCII` should work.

Instead of `setString()` you could also keep `write()` as you do, with the 0-terminated `byte[]` argument.

Alternately if you want to use an array mapping in the function instead of a `Pointer`, just declare a new array:

```java
// initializes all elements to 0
byte[] appnameNullTerminated = new byte[appname.length+1];
System.arraycopy(appname, 0, appnameNullTerminated, 0, appname.length);
```

Or, use the above and write that terminated `byte[]` array as you do now.

Again, make sure you control the encoding of the characters to bytes. Using `getBytes()` without specifying an encoding is generally a bad idea.